TikZ Pictures in a table
I would like to fit three tikz pictures in a raw of a table (code below). I keep getting the following error:
> ! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX
> Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help....
> \begin

three times at each

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.70]

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks a lot.

Here is my code:
\documentclass{amstext-l}
\usepackage{geometry}
\paperheight=24cm
\paperwidth=17cm
\textheight=19.2cm
\textwidth=13cm
\hoffset=-1.8cm
\voffset=-0.3cm
\oddsidemargin=1.3cm
\usepackage[italian]{babel}    
\usepackage{graphicx}        
\usepackage{multicol}        
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}

%\usepackage{showkeys}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{fancybox} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
%**************************************************

%******************************************************************
%\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%***************************************************************

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, quotes}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.70]
    \begin{axis}[view={25}{25},colormap={blackwhite}{gray(0cm)=(0); gray(1cm)=(1)}, 
hide axis, % Hide the axes 
xticklabel=\empty,
yticklabel=\empty,
zticklabel=\empty,
xtick=\empty,
ytick=\empty,
ztick=\empty]
\addplot3 [surf,shader=faceted,z buffer=sort,
samples=30,domain=0:360,y domain=-2:2]
                ({cosh(y)*cos(x)},{cosh(y)*sin(x)},{sinh(y)});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{small}
\captionsetup{labelformat=empty}
\caption{a} 
\end{small}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.70]
    \begin{axis}[view={25}{25},colormap={blackwhite}{gray(0cm)=(0); gray(1cm)=(1)}, 
hide axis, % Hide the axes 
xticklabel=\empty,
yticklabel=\empty,
zticklabel=\empty,
xtick=\empty,
ytick=\empty,
ztick=\empty]
\addplot3 [surf,shader=faceted,z buffer=sort,
samples=30,domain=0:360,y domain=0:180]
                ({cos(x)*sin(y)},{sin(x)*sin(y)},{cos(y)});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{small}
\captionsetup{labelformat=empty}
\caption{b} 
\end{small}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.70]
\begin{axis}[colormap={blackwhite}{gray(0cm)=(0); gray(1cm)=(1)}, 
hide axis, % Hide the axes 
xticklabel=\empty,
yticklabel=\empty,
zticklabel=\empty,
xtick=\empty,
ytick=\empty,
ztick=\empty,
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$,
        zlabel=$z$,
        domain=0:2,
        samples=30,
        view={60}{20},
    ]
        \addplot3[surf, surf,shader=faceted,z buffer=sort, variable=\u, variable y=\v, y domain=90:270] ({sinh(\u) * cos(\v)}, {sinh(\u) * sin(\v)}, {cosh(\u)});
        \addplot3[surf, surf,shader=faceted,z buffer=sort, variable=\u, variable y=\v, y domain=-90:90] ({sinh(\u) * cos(\v)}, {sinh(\u) * sin(\v)}, {cosh(\u)});
        \addplot3[surf, surf,shader=faceted,z buffer=sort, variable=\u, variable y=\v, y domain=90:270] ({sinh(\u) * cos(\v)}, {sinh(\u) * sin(\v)}, {-cosh(\u)});
        \addplot3[surf, surf,shader=faceted,z buffer=sort, variable=\u, variable y=\v, y domain=-90:90] ({sinh(\u) * cos(\v)}, {sinh(\u) * sin(\v)}, {-cosh(\u)});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{small}
\captionsetup{labelformat=empty}
\caption{c} 
\end{small}
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\end{center}

\end{document} 


Please provide the missing relevant code lines, so we can compile a copy. A screenshot or sketch of your intended result may help, too. Thank you

I posted the entire code. There result should be as follows: the three tikz picures should appear one next to the other in a row, each one with its caption just below.

! LaTeX Error: File \amstext-l.cls' not found.`  can you not show the problem with a standard document class, or give a link to this class at least? It is not in texlive.

Thank you. // "Entire code" is bad, as, especially in your case, it can lead to an useless update nightmare, jsut to see a result. Please remove, what's not needed in your posted code.

See also subfigure or \subfloat from the subcaption package.  No tabular needed, just don't add blank l;ines between them.

Remove the figure that are inside the tabular, being in a table is not consistent with being able to float to another page.
Have a single figure around the tabular so the whole construct may float, you can syill \caption each part separately.

after code was supplied in the question...
Also the captions need to be in a vertical mode you can not have them in a c column, use p.  Never put a figure in a center envioronment, it doesn't center it, and adds vertical space at that point even if the figure floats to a different place.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\paperheight=24cm
\paperwidth=17cm
\textheight=19.2cm
\textwidth=13cm
\hoffset=-1.8cm
\voffset=-0.3cm
\oddsidemargin=1.3cm
\usepackage[italian]{babel}    
\usepackage{graphicx}        
\usepackage{multicol}        
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}

%\usepackage{showkeys}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{fancybox} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
%**************************************************

%******************************************************************
%\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%***************************************************************

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, quotes}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\begin{document}

% no\begin{center}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
\begin{tabular}{p{.3\textwidth}p{.3\textwidth}p{.3\textwidth}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.70]
    \begin{axis}[view={25}{25},colormap={blackwhite}{gray(0cm)=(0); gray(1cm)=(1)}, 
hide axis, % Hide the axes 
xticklabel=\empty,
yticklabel=\empty,
zticklabel=\empty,
xtick=\empty,
ytick=\empty,
ztick=\empty]
\addplot3 [surf,shader=faceted,z buffer=sort,
samples=30,domain=0:360,y domain=-2:2]
                ({cosh(y)*cos(x)},{cosh(y)*sin(x)},{sinh(y)});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{small}
\captionsetup{labelformat=empty}
\caption{a} 
\end{small}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.70]
    \begin{axis}[view={25}{25},colormap={blackwhite}{gray(0cm)=(0); gray(1cm)=(1)}, 
hide axis, % Hide the axes 
xticklabel=\empty,
yticklabel=\empty,
zticklabel=\empty,
xtick=\empty,
ytick=\empty,
ztick=\empty]
\addplot3 [surf,shader=faceted,z buffer=sort,
samples=30,domain=0:360,y domain=0:180]
                ({cos(x)*sin(y)},{sin(x)*sin(y)},{cos(y)});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{small}
\captionsetup{labelformat=empty}
\caption{b} 
\end{small}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.70]
\begin{axis}[colormap={blackwhite}{gray(0cm)=(0); gray(1cm)=(1)}, 
hide axis, % Hide the axes 
xticklabel=\empty,
yticklabel=\empty,
zticklabel=\empty,
xtick=\empty,
ytick=\empty,
ztick=\empty,
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$,
        zlabel=$z$,
        domain=0:2,
        samples=30,
        view={60}{20},
    ]
        \addplot3[surf, surf,shader=faceted,z buffer=sort, variable=\u, variable y=\v, y domain=90:270] ({sinh(\u) * cos(\v)}, {sinh(\u) * sin(\v)}, {cosh(\u)});
        \addplot3[surf, surf,shader=faceted,z buffer=sort, variable=\u, variable y=\v, y domain=-90:90] ({sinh(\u) * cos(\v)}, {sinh(\u) * sin(\v)}, {cosh(\u)});
        \addplot3[surf, surf,shader=faceted,z buffer=sort, variable=\u, variable y=\v, y domain=90:270] ({sinh(\u) * cos(\v)}, {sinh(\u) * sin(\v)}, {-cosh(\u)});
        \addplot3[surf, surf,shader=faceted,z buffer=sort, variable=\u, variable y=\v, y domain=-90:90] ({sinh(\u) * cos(\v)}, {sinh(\u) * sin(\v)}, {-cosh(\u)});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{small}
\captionsetup{labelformat=empty}
\caption{c} 
\end{small}
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
% no\end{center}

\end{document} 

I used article class rather than the non standard class in the question that I do not have.

I did as you said but it does not compile, it starts but does not stop.

Thanks a lot. Now, it works. However not all captions are centered with respect to the pictures (see the image above). The second row is fine. How can I center the captions in the first and third row?
